# Error while executing randomForest when the number of trees are increased beyond a certain number

Tags: r, random-forest

I was running radomForest model. The model is running fine till 722 trees. But if I increase the number of trees to more than 722, I’m getting the below error:

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMuoa.png)

Since the model is running fine till 722 trees, I was wondering if it could be a memory issue. Do you think there is any way to validate this or find out what the error is?

Please find below the details of the dataset:
•   File size: 63MB
•   # of obs.: 742,599
•   # of columns: 17 (all numeric expect for the response variable)

Answer (score 1):

You are using the randomForest package?, another option would be to use
[spark.randomForest {SparkR}](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/R/spark.randomForest.html) or [h2o.randomForest](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/h2o/versions/3.16.0.2/topics/h2o.randomForest), these packages offer greater capacity of execution in big data, in the following [link](http://datascience.la/benchmarking-random-forest-implementations/) they compared the algorithms of random forest for observations of 10 million, the best options are h2o and xgboost.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I will try it out. But I would like to know if there is a way to determine this error I'm getting is a memory error?

Comment: You can determine this by looking at the task manager in windows. Does the used ram increase until the limit and then R is breaking down?

Comment: Thank you for the response. I'm using an RStudio server instance through web interface, hence, unable to check the task manager to monitor RAM performance.